# Dynamic directive naming on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to have all attributes or elements named `ns-directive-*` to call only one one directive `ns-directive`?

Comment: Have you considered doing something like `ns-directive="hello"`, then using a switch statement within the directive?

Comment: Example Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/C6KlZhWZddr70yzNqlHV?p=preview

Comment: yes of course, but the attribute content should be used for something else. i can of course send objects like `ns-directive="{a:'hello', b:'wildcard'}"` but having a dynamic directive name is convenient for my use case.

Comment: No. What @MorganDelaney proposes is probably your best bet. You can use as many attributes as you'd like on an element (e.g. `<element ns-directive a="hello" b="wildcard" ...>`) or what you show could be fine too.

Comment: I think it's just not possible. angularjs do it with `ng-attr-*` but apparently it's hardcoded into the *collectDirectives* comoile function.